# RegEx for validating three alphanumeric conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have the current regex that works fine:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$
```

It works for existing pattern containing exactly 2 letters followed by exacly 8 digits, such as AB12345678 or yZ01928374

I need to change it to a new regex that satisfies 3 conditions:

1) if the first 2 letters are followed by a single digit "9", then it can be followed by 7 or 8 digits `[0-9]{7,8}`. Eg `AB91234567` or `AC912345678` are both valid.

2) if the first 2 letters are followed by a single digit between 0-5, then it can be followed by exactly 8 digits `[0-9]{8}`. Eg `AB412345678`

3) if the first 2 letters are followed by digit between 6-8, then it can be followed by exactly 7 digits `[0-9]{7}`. Eg `AB71234567`

I've got bits and pieces but I'm really not sure how to put all 3 conditions together in 1 nice expression.

Comment: Btw, this is what I came up with, but I have idea if it actually works:

^[a-zA-Z]{2}+(9\d[0-9]{7,8}|\d[0-5]{1}\d[0-9]{8}|\d[6-8]{1}\d[0-9]{7})$

Comment: One alternation is missing here `|\d[6-8]{1}\d|[0-9]{7})$` other than that it looks fine and that `+` is not needed

Comment: You basically need alternations to handle your three cases. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56118256/2102956) and the explanation and demo. And the regex you mentioned in your comments is a little incorrect. You don't need `+` after `{2}` and don't need to write both `\d[0-9]` instead just need to write either `\d` or `[0-9]` for representing a digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternations to define different conditions and use this regex,

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:9[0-9]{7,8}|[0-5][0-9]{8}|[6-8][0-9]{7})$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - Matches two alphabets
- `(?:` - Start of non-grouping pattern
- `9[0-9]{7,8}` - If the next digit is `9` then  it can be followed by 7 to 8 digits
- `|` - Alternation
- `[0-5][0-9]{8}` - If the next digit is zero to five then it can only have eight digits
- `|` - Alternation
- `[6-8][0-9]{7})` - If the next digit is six to eight then it can only have seven digits and end of non-group pattern
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C5x0Du/1/)**

JS Code demo,

```js
const arr = ['ab91234567','ab912345678','ab9123456789','sd012345678','sd0123456789','df71234567','df712345678']

arr.forEach(x => console.log(x + " --> " + /^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:9[0-9]{7,8}|[0-5][0-9]{8}|[6-8][0-9]{7})$/.test(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**alternation**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and add the desired rules for values followed by after first two alphabets

```js
let test = ['AB91234567','AB412345678','AB912','ABC123']

test.forEach( value => {
  console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:9\d{7,8}|[0-5]\d{8}|[6-8]\d{7})$/.test(value))
})
```